# Two has_many :through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `Driver` and `Block`, which interact through two `has_many :through` relationships:

`Driver` has many `Blocks` through `Permanent`, and

`Driver` has many `Blocks` through `Available`

In the view, I have checkboxes for the collection of blocks that look like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag("driver[block_ids][]", block.id) %>
```

This works well when I only had one "through" model, 'Available', but how does it work when I have two?

---

An alternative way to do this would be to have one "though" model, `Available`, which has a boolean called "permanent" to indicate if it's the other type.

But I don't know how I can pass the boolean value using checkboxes in the view. Currently, the checkboxes dictate whether a HABTM-style link exists, but have no extra params.

```
<%= check_box_tag("driver[block_ids][]", block.id) %>
```

---

A third way to do it would be to use nested forms to create each `Permanent` or `Available` link.

I can create one form for each `Permanent` or `Available`, each of which has an hidden "block_id" parameter. This would lead to over 100 forms on the page, which feels wrong, but it would probably work.

Comment: You can also try `STI(Single table Inheritance)` `class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base` and then `class Permanent < Driver` and `class Available < Driver`

Comment: For your second way, you can pass type as `= check_box_tag "driver[]", block.id, block.type`

Comment: Isn't the third parameter for check_box_tag is the checked value `check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. `check_box_tag "driver[]", { :id => block.id, :type => block.type }`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would work for you to try just having one association and then you can create a scope for available and permanent.

```
has_many Blocks

scope :available, -> { where(available: true) }
scope :permanent, -> { where(permanent: true) }
```